# Almacenar en MySQL array parseado con PHP

Tags: php, array, api, while

Tengo una API que me devuelve un array con 25 resultados diferentes cada vez que la invoco.
Este resultado logré parsearlo por cada nombre de campo que llega.

Ejemplo de cómo recibo la info:

> id:1,fecha:2019-01-01:10:01:01,usuario:user1,id:2,fecha:2019-01-01:10:02:01,usuario:user2 ... y así con 23 registros más.

Utilizando la función de str_replace() consigo mostrar los resultados de esta manera:

```
$resultado = str_replace( array("id","fecha","usuario"), array("<br>id","<br>fecha","<br>usuario"), $mi_array);
```

> id:1
>
> fecha:2019-01-01:10:01:01
>
> usuario:user1
>
> id:2
>
> fecha:2019-01-01:10:02:01
>
> usuario:user2

Lo que necesitaría es crear un while que me permita por cada grupo de resultados almacenar cada campo en una tabla.

Es posible esto?

Comment: Hay algunas razon por la que no envias un json para trabajar con un array asociativo?

Comment: La única razón es que no tengo mucha experiencia programando y desconozco las distintas alternativas que existen. Por eso llegué a la opción del array parseado. Cómo debería usar el json? Recuerda que la API me devuelve un array.

Comment: Osea, la api te devuelve un string separado por comas con todos los registros en el?

Comment: Exacto de esta forma: id:1,fecha:2019-01-01:10:01:01,usuario:user1,id:2,fecha:2019-01-01:10:02:01,usuario:user2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posiblemente haya maneras más óptimas de hacerlo, pero los datos están formateados un poco raros, al ser todo un string seguido separado por comas, sin ningún delimitador entre registros.

```
<?php

    $string = 'id:1,fecha:2019-01-01:10:01:01,usuario:user1,id:2,fecha:2019-01-01:10:02:01,usuario:user2'; // String devuelto

    $registros = explode("id:", $string); // Separamos cada registro

    $arrayFormateado = []; // Array donde guardaremos los datos formateados

    array_shift($registros); // Sacamos el registro null del principio

    foreach ($registros as $r) {

        $array = []; // Array donde vamos guardando el registros

        foreach (str_getcsv('id:' . $r) as $dato){ // str_getcsv Convierte un string con datos separados por un delimitador en un array

            if ($dato === '') { // Saltamos en caso de que tengamos algun dato vacio

                continue; 

            }

            $key = explode(':', $dato)[0]; // Sacamos la llave

            $value = explode(':', $dato, 2)[1]; // Sacamos el valor

            $array[$key] = $value;

        }

        $arrayFormateado[] = $array;

    }

    foreach ($arrayFormateado as $reg) {
        // Logica para grabar en base de datos

        // Los datos podran ser accedidos de la siguiente manera:
        // $reg['id'];
        // $reg['fecha'];
        // $reg['usuario'];
    }

?>
```

Esto te formatea lo que recibes y te lo prepara para que puedas agregar en bucle los datos.

Comment: Pero falta la parte que pide de "almacenar cada campo en una tabla", no? Has procesado la información, pero no le has explicado como separar esa info para subirlo a la BD, supongo que cada campo en su correspondiente columna y no tabla.

Comment: En si pregunta como poder hacer un bucle para grabar los registros, claro que podriamos añadir la logica para grabar, pero no tenemos nada sobre que tipo de BBDD, etc usa. Por eso se lo deje hasta el bucle. Aunque si que conviene que explique como utilizar los datos. Ahora lo editare.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias! Funciona casi a la perfección. Lo único que no estoy pudiendo ver son las horas:minutos:segundos del campo fecha, entiendo que se están omitiendo por el ":", hay forma de no omitirlos?

Comment: Perdon, se me paso por alto eso. Si es por el explode, he editado la respuesta añadiendo un 2 al explode. esto evitara que perdamos la hora.

Comment: @Francisco Toda la razón tienes. Ha quedado chachi el código.

Comment: Muchas gracias crack! Anda perfecto.